# NettyConnectorFactory error

Tags: jms, netty, hornetq

I have a Jms Listener inside a tomcat application. The JMS server is a hornetQ server and I use netty connector to connect to it. The connection is successful and works fine, but when tomcat stops, I see the following error in catalina.out

`Dec 11, 2014 4:31:40 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1245)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1205)
        at org.hornetq.utils.ClassloadingUtil.newInstanceFromClassLoader(ClassloadingUtil.java:24)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$2.run(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1466)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$2.run(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1463)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.instantiateConnectorFactory(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1462)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:203)
        at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:864)
        at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:583)
        at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:107)
        at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:102)
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:184)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.createSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:405)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.refreshSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:390)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:880)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.recoverAfterListenerSetupFailure(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:856)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1007)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Dec 11, 2014 4:31:40 PM org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable
WARNING: Failed to determine the thread name
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.getNewThreadName(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:126)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:91)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.VirtualExecutorService$ChildExecutorRunnable.run(VirtualExecutorService.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)`

I know this is because tomcat illegally stops the connector but I am not sure how to fix this!

Comment: So do you mean to say you have created jar with jms listener and placed in tomcat lib directory? Some configuration details too would help us

Comment: I have created a war with a listener based on this blog:

http://techannotation.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/spring-jms-produce-and-consume-messages/

I am not sure if I can modify the configuration someway to stop these errors.

Comment: So previously you were creating jar and placing it in lib directory ? Anyways you could implement with jar as well(the handling configuration changes a tedious task
)but you need to rigester tomcat start/stop listener and on stop you need to do clean up activity.

Comment: @KarthikPrasad sorry as I was on vacation. so previously it was a standalone application but now I need to update some data structures in my tomcat application with the data from the JMS topic. I underdtand you are hinting towards creating a jar and placing it in the library directory but I do not know how to move forward. I can even try to register a start/stop listener but incase the tomcat is started/stopped via a service command, will that work? (service tomcat5 start/stop/restart).

Comment: Yes you can handle based on varies events generated by tomcat such as AFTER_START_EVENT,AFTER_STOP_EVENT, BEFORE_START_EVENT, BEFORE_STOP_EVENT, DESTROY_EVENT, INIT_EVENT, PERIODIC_EVENT, START_EVENT, STOP_EVENT,you can use appropriate event. The interface is  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleListener. Anyways I would suggest to use webapps and load the spring configuration from webapps/use contextloader. For its maintainability. creating jar  and placing it tomcat lib would have more dependencies as well as spring dependency issue if you have (few extra)spring jars in webapp/lib directory